# MySQL partitioning vs changing to MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, optimization, bigdata, database-partitioning

We have 4 pretty large tables in a MySQL database.  They are about 50, 35, 6 and 5 Gb, other tables aren't so large. These tables are full of analytic data which is appended by cron tasks every 10 minutes.  These tables will continue to grow over time.

Here is schema of a datatable

```
CREATE TABLE `instpld` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `insID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dbID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `count` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_count` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `insID` (`insID`(50)),
  KEY `dbID` (`dbID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I understand that types of fields could be much better.  The question is what is better - adding some partitioning on the table or switch everything to MongoDB because it is faster?

I am looking for pros and cons of each option.

```
# Misc Settings
# -------------
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/var/lib/mysqltmp
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
#skip-locking
skip-name-resolve
#table_cache=2048
thread_cache_size=16
back_log=100
max_connect_errors=10000
open-files-limit=20000
interactive_timeout=3600
wait_timeout=600
#max_connections=200
# Added to prevent DNS lookups from causing performance issues
skip-name-resolve

# Set this to change the way MySQL handles validation, data
# conversion, etc. Be careful with this setting as it can
# cause unexpected results and horribly break some applications!
# Note, too, that it can be set per-session and can be hard set
# in stored procedures.
#sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

# Slow Query Log Settings
# -----------------------
#log-slow-queries=/var/lib/mysqllogs/slow-log
#long_query_time=2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

# Global, Non Engine-Specific Buffers
# -----------------------------------
max_allowed_packet=16M
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M

# Generally, it is unwise to set the query cache to be
# larger than 64-128M as this can decrease performance
# since the penalty for flushing the cache can become
# significant.
query_cache_size=32M
skip-name-resolve

# Set this to change the way MySQL handles validation, data
# conversion, etc. Be careful with this setting as it can
# cause unexpected results and horribly break some applications!
# Note, too, that it can be set per-session and can be hard set
# in stored procedures.
#sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

# Slow Query Log Settings
# -----------------------
#log-slow-queries=/var/lib/mysqllogs/slow-log
#long_query_time=2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

# Global, Non Engine-Specific Buffers
# -----------------------------------
max_allowed_packet=16M
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M

# Generally, it is unwise to set the query cache to be
# larger than 64-128M as this can decrease performance
# since the penalty for flushing the cache can become
# significant.
query_cache_size=32M

# Per-Thread Buffers
# ------------------
sort_buffer_size=1M
read_buffer_size=1M
read_rnd_buffer_size=8M
join_buffer_size=1M
key_buffer_size=64M

# This setting controls the size of the buffer that is allocated when
# sorting MyISAM indexes during a REPAIR TABLE or when creating indexes
# with CREATE INDEX or ALTER TABLE.
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M

# InnoDB
# ------
# Note: While most settings in MySQL can be set at run-time, InnoDB
# variables require restarting MySQL to apply.

# If the customer already has InnoDB tables and wants to change the
# size of the InnoDB tablespace and InnoDB logs, then:
# 1. Run a full backup with mysqldump
# 2. Stop MySQL
# 3. Move current ibdata and ib_logfiles out of /var/lib/mysql
# 4. Uncomment the below innodb_data_file_path and innodb_log_file_size
# 5. Start MySQL (it will recreate new InnoDB files)
# 6. Restore data from backup
#innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_file_size=100M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G

........
```

Comment: MySQL uses hard disks to store data. MongoDB uses hard disks to store data. MySQL reads data from disk. MongoDB reads data from disk. For some reason, you apparently think that MongoDB has some secret code that lets it use the disk better. It doesn't. It won't work faster if you move it there. It's only going to be prone to data loss and you'll think it's faster. Optimizing tables like those you have depends on your server, available RAM and overall speed of disk(s). There's just insufficient info from you, you should include the config variables of your MySQL instance.

Comment: thanks for the comment. We have 128 gb ram server, and about 110 gb used by current db. i'll update the post with the config soon.

Comment: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz stepping 07

Comment: If I could upvote N.B.'s comment more than once I would. Mongodb *is* subject to the same limitations as mysql. But from the information you have provided there seems to be a *lot* of scope for speeding up your database, and a lot of evidence that you have not spent much effort trying to make it go faster.  But how to tune your dB is too complex a question to answer here. You might start by running mysqltuner.pl

Comment: @symcbean -- I upvoted it for you (and me).

Comment: What kind of query response times are you getting from your largest tables on reading a row? Are you looking to optimise reads or writes at the moment? Do you have a performance problem right now, or are you expecting one in the future?

Comment: Are you just inserting into these tables or are you performing queries? Inserts can be optimized in your case, you said you are using cron to populate tables. If that's the case, we could help you optimize that step. However, it's unclear which part of your system is slow - the querying or inserting data.

Answer (score 2):

You have 128GB, use it!  `innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G` -- change to around 70% of RAM.

I'll bet you can't show me an `EXPLAIN` that uses `KEY instaID (instaID(50))`.  Prefixes indexes are almost always unused.

Turn on the slowlog, gather some data, run pt-query-digest, then show us the "worst" query.  Provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for it.

`id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,` -- I hope you are not expecting 20-digit numbers.  This will max out a little above 2 billion.

If we can't optimize your queries, then we will move into Data Warehousing techniques, such as Summary Tables -- they tend to give 10x speedup.

Comment: People usually miss out on buffer_pool, good you mentioned that :) have my upvote.

Comment: Yeah, I got so tired of pointing it out, that I wrote a blog with the main details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory .

Answer (score 0):

Its really impossible to answer with no knowledge about how you use it or what bottleneck you will be facing first.

Remember Innodb has some problems with size if you dont optimize the table once in a while.

Comment: No -- OPTIMIZE TABLE is almost never needed for InnoDB.

Comment: Buddy you gotta go read a bit: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Comment: @RickJames is actually correct here. `OPTIMIZE` is  not needed. Documentation might hint it is, but it's not. `OPTIMIZE` on InnoDB will perform recreate and analyze. It will drop the table and re-insert everything. If the table **is not** under heavy delete or update, this step is useless and all it will do is add to the load of the server for quite literally **no gain**. Remember, right tool for the job. OPTIMIZE in OP's scenario is not needed. What he does need is do what Rick mentioned in his answer - Increase the buffer pool.

Comment: OP changed his subject after I wrote about the optimize. So I had no way of knowing if it was under heavy delete action. And the "OPTIMIZE TABLE is almost never needed for InnoDB." is a more general statement, which is plain wrong. Our databases would have an overhead of more than 100 gb if we didnt optimize them sometimes.